# Another declined flag, should I reflag?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I flagged this answer as "not an answer" and the flag was declined. Am I missing something?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36682162/483620

The answer, posted by the OP reads, word for word:

> Pretty much yes – RiggsFolly 4 hours ago

In this case, should I just ignore the moderator's decision and reflag? Ask on meta? Do nothing?

Comment: Did you read the question?

Comment: @Shog9: Yes. It looks like some comments or discussion that happened were deleted? We wouldn't accept that answer on any other question, without some explanation or details, so I don't see how it works here.

Comment: @Benjamin ignore everything you wrote in your comment, it is irrelevant. Does the answer address the question as asked? If so, then it is an answer. Might be a bad answer, but it is an answer. And bad answers shouldn't be flagged, they should be downvoted if you feel something isn't right.

Comment: Tag this [flags]

Comment: This is why yes/no questions are bad.

Comment: Just want to say, I appreciate @Andrew Li for pointing me to the canonical answer, and Stephen Leppik for the direct answer. Maybe the text from that meta post "[this flag] should NOT be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" should go next to the flagging option in the flagging dialog, to avoid "surprises" like this. As it stands, the text hints that "not attempting" to answer the question is indeed grounds for flagging.

Comment: @Benjamin actually, I copy/pasted that from one of my declined flags. It's one of the templated decline reasons for VLQ/NaA.

Comment: @StephenLeppik: It is also listed in the linked question... If it's a template reason to decline the flag, why not show it explicitly, in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it turns out, "yes" *is in fact* an answer.

Not a *good* one, but repeat after me:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Comment: Is it a very low quality answer, though?